# Postgres: Reclaiming Space

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, vacuum

I have a server with 150GB of diskspace. Today I uploaded a dataset of 30GB. I cancelled the import due to internet dying, then noticed there was 29GB of space missing in the database (meaning the CSV was uploaded, but not deleted when I broke the operation). When uploading the data once again, it broke again and I lost another ~25GB. Now there isn't enough free space to upload the data.

This is hosted on AWS RDS, Postgres 10.6.

Is there a way to fix this? I read about `VACUUM`. But will this delete records? I'm hosting at the moment ~70GB of data and don't want to lose any records. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: `vacuum full` is what you need, and no it will not delete any rows, it just frees up space

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name will this lock up tables so that for example users cannot register? 

The table with the data is named "data" can't i just run "VACUUM DATA" or will it not also free up previously uploaded datasets? 

Another question, will VACUUM also delete previously uploaded datasets/failed uploads? Sorry for bombardment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL leaves dead data in the table; the space can be reused, but the files won't shrink (significantly).

The official method to reclaim space is `VACUUM (FULL)`, but that rewrites the whole table, which will be unavailable for any access during that time. There are extensions called `pg_squeeze` and `pg_repack` which do the same thing with less disruption "behind the scenes".

All these methods have in common that they will require enough free space to create a copy of the table, so you probably won't get around increasing the storage space anyway.

**Now for the good news:**

If you run a plain `VACUUM` on the table, which is not disruptive, the wasted space can be reused. So your next attempt to load the data won't increase the size of the table.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe. I'm running this at the moment :). Will this also freeup the previously uploaded data sets e.g. the missing ~55GB?

Comment: Plain `VACUUM` will not shrink the data files, but it will free the space within. So the disk usage won't go down, but your next attempt has room enough.